# What is the basic unit of a chain called in English?

Tags: word-request, image-identification

Chains are made of a lot of oval shaped units. What is each one of them called in English?

I don't know the name in my native language either.

[image: a metal chain with a red arrow pointing to one of its links]

Answer (score 70, accepted):

It's called a **link**. From Wikipedia,

> A chain is a series of connected **links** which are typically made of metal. A chain may consist of two or more **links**.

Comment: There's an interesting idiomatic expression, "a chain is only as strong as its weakest link." It means, for instance, that the weakest member of a team or process might disproportionately affect the rest negatively.

Comment: Note that a "link" can also refer to a number of other things (e.g. a [hypertext link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperlink)). Often it's clear from the context which one is meant, in which case you can just say "link", but if necessary you can say "link of a chain" to clarify what sort of link you mean.

Comment: It's the same underlying meaning: a *link* is something that connects (or could connect) two things. In the case of a physical chain, each link connects two other links to each other, or to whatever the chain is attached to.

Comment: Also, a lot of idiomatic phrases involving chains use "link" as well: "The weakest link", "The missing link", "Link up", etc..

Answer (score -2):

You could also use "ring".

In support of this, [from the Cambridge dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/chain), a chain is "a set of connected things". In particular, look at the second definition: "(a length of) rings". The word "link" never appears on the page, even though I can agree with the @Max's definition.

Almost the same is stated in the [Oxford dictionary - chain](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/chain_1?q=chain):

> [countable, uncountable] a series of connected metal **rings**, used for pulling or fastening things; a length of chain used for a particular purpose

Comment: While it certainly is a ring, that doesn't imply that it's part of a chain in the same way link does.

Comment: I partially agree with you.
Of course, it's right that a ring doesn't necessary belong to a chain. However, it is also true that also a link it is not always part of a chain: nodes in a net are linked, but they don't shape a chain: they shape a net.

So, it is very common that material chains are made of rings; even though sometimes they are not.

Comment: I should add from the [Cambridge dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/chain), that a [chain](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/chain) is "a set of connected things". In particular, look at the second definition: "(a length of) rings". The word "link" never appear on the page, even though I can agree with the @Max definition.

Almost the same is stated on the [Oxford dictionary - chain](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/chain).

Comment: I'm glad you decided to edit your answer to include more information. I think that "ring" is a common alternative to "link" and that the picture in the question may have biased folks toward "link". A picture of a [chain with more rounded "links"](http://vintaj.com/pic/CH50.jpg) might have made people look more favorably on the suggestion of "rings", which is less specific than "links" but not incorrect.

Comment: Would definitely be more inclined to upvote this answer if it referenced some picture with *round* links. But at the moment I rather disagree with the part that says "especially in the case of the picture you posted" because the links in that picture aren't round.

Comment: At risk of beating a dead horse, I think using a dictionary as proof positive is a mistake. The definition of "link" will certainly include the word "chain", so defining a chain as being a collection of links is circular and unhelpful. By its form, a _ring_; by its function, a _link_.

Comment: Languages have plenty of redundancies, and words are not just logically defined. So, I could only partially agree with you about the distinction between link and from. However, the connotation of "ring" goes beyond the merely identified shape.